# Can't perform median() on a raster stack in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I'm trying to find the per cell median across a set of rasters in R, but when I use the `median` function I get the following error:

```
Error in if (any(is.na(x))) return(x[FALSE][NA]) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

However, I can perform `max`, `mean` and `calc(r, median)` on my stack so I suspect that it isn't an issue with data format (tif). The code I'm using is:

Load data:

```
f = list.files("./")
r = stack(f)
```

Do sums:

```
median(r) # does not work
mean(r) # works
max(r) # works
calc(r, median) # works
```

As `calc` is working I don't need an answer to proceed, but I would like to understand why `median` isn't working. Is this standard behaviour?

Comment: Because `median` is not a summary method available for Raster* objects. Available summary methods are currently `mean`, `max`, `min`, `range`, `prod`, `sum`, `any` and `all`. Source: [reference manual, page 201](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf)

Comment: @Pascal consider putting this into an answer and don't forget to tell where this information is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf), p. 201:

> The following summary methods are available for Raster* objects:
>   `mean`, `max`, `min`, `range`, `prod`, `sum`, `any`, `all`

`median` is not a summary method available for Raster* objects. That is why you need to use `calc` function.

Comment: `median()` is also absent from Spark R with Spark 1.6.2 - (This answer helped me realize that)